# Jetpack Compose - Centering Text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-layout

I am using Jetpack Compose to create a simple flash card.
The idea is that you click the flash card and it will give you the answer.
However, I am stuck on a basic problem.

Unfortunately... I could not even find the official documentation, so my learning style has been trusting the autocorrect system...

Anyway, I believe the issue is either with Box() or Text().
I have added a Align.CenterEnd for the Gravity of the box. However, this seems to be the only way for centering in terms for the box. On the other hand, Text() does not give any methods to do so (It has gravity but it doesnt seem to be changing anything)

A hand in the right direction would be amazing.

On a side note, I know this would be giving free answers. But how would I change the text of $question inside the on click. As I thought Composables refresh?... thus, should regenerate on the screen? maybe not?

Thanks!

```
 val typography = MaterialTheme.typography

        val context = ContextAmbient.current
        var question = "How many Bananas should go in my Smoothie?"


        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(30.dp).then(Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
                .then(Modifier.wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center))
                .clickable(onClick = { Toast.makeText(context, "3 Bananas are needed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()} ) /*question = "3 Bananas required"*/
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(350.dp)
                    .gravity(align = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                    .border(width = 4.dp, color = Gray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(2.dp),
            backgroundColor = DarkGray,
            gravity = Alignment.CenterEnd) {
                Text("$question",
                style = typography.h4,
                )
            }
        }
```

[image: Picture of Current Content]

Comment: What do you mean with centering text? The Text is centered in your Box. What are you looking for? A justify style?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

To define how to align the text **horizontally** you can apply [**`textAlign = TextAlign.Center`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextAlign) in the `Text`:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(30.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
            .clickable(onClick = { } ) /*question = "3 Bananas required"*/
            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)),
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
            .preferredSize(350.dp)
            .border(width = 4.dp, color = Gray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)),
             alignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(
           text = "Question 1 : How many cars are in the garage?",
           modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
           textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
           style = typography.h4,
        )
      //... 
   }
}
```

[image]

About the text.

You can use something like:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf(("How many cars are in the garage?")) }
```

In your clickable item:

```
.clickable(onClick = { text= "After clicking"} )
```

in your Text:

```
  Text(text, 
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        ...)
```

It is just a simple. Instead of a static String you can use a dynamic structure to store and update the value.

Comment: Thanks, the TextAlign was helpful. Is there official documentation for compose for each class? Ive been pretty confused on learning it.

Comment: @PandaPlaysAll Here you can find all [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/classes). I've updated the answer with the link to `TextAlign`

Comment: How can you align text to bottom or top? There is no option in TextAlignment for that?

Answer (score 65):

You can use `textAlign` to align your text horizontal and `wrapContentHeight` to align your text vertical within `Text` composable

**Example centering text (both horizontal and vertical) within `Text`**

```
Text(
    text = "How many cars are in the garage",
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center, // make text center horizontal
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(150.dp)
        .height(150.dp)
        .background(Color.Cyan)
        .wrapContentHeight() // make text center vertical
)
```

**Example align bottom with center horizontal within `Text`**

```
Text(
    text = "How many cars are in the garage",
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center, // make text center horizontal
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(150.dp)
        .height(150.dp)
        .background(Color.Cyan)
        .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.Bottom) // align bottom
)
```

**Example align bottom with center horizontal within a `Box`**

```
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .width(150.dp)
    .height(150.dp)
    .background(Color.Cyan),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
) {
    Text(
        text = "How many cars are in the garage",
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}
```

Comment: doesn't when you have for example `minLines = 3`  and currently `Text` contains only one line, it's still centered only horizontally but not vertically

Comment: @user924 This is true, `minLines` does cause the height to increase but the text stays at the top. This is the work around I use: https://github.com/imashnake0/Animite/blob/8a7d0d45a0a51741edf204fb0d5a1ad14716b6dd/app/src/main/java/com/imashnake/animite/features/ui/MediaSmall.kt#L107-L135

Comment: You can use `size(150.dp)` instead of `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 8):

```
Box(
contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
 modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
){
    Text(
      text = "Text",
      textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile. Please fix your code

Answer (score 7):

The following works for me:

```
Text(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), text = "TEST", textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// You can apply textAlign = TextAlign.Center

 Text( text = "My name is $name",
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
        fontSize = 32.sp,
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Cursive,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Hello Friends"Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })
```