# How to center (horizontally and vertically) text in Jetpack Compose Text

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a large `Text`.

```
Text(
    text = "Select Bank account",
    color = Color.White,
    fontSize = 18.sp,
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Black)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(16.dp)
        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
)
```

[image]

How to center the text both vertically and horizontally?

In a view-based system, we can achieve this using `Gravity.CENTER`.
Looking for a similar solution.

**Note**
Looking for a solution without using another component wrapping the text. (`Box`, `Column`, etc).

I am aware that my requirement can be achieved using a wrapper component as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719072/jetpack-compose-centering-text).

Comment: You could use `fillMaxSize().wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically)`

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by adding similar xml attribute like **"wrap_content"** as height in compose too.

Add **"wrapContentHeight()"** to modifier and you will get it to align to centre of the page.

```
Text(
        text = "Select Bank account",
        color = Color.White,
        fontSize = 18.sp,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Black)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(16.dp)
    )
```

Comment: Is this vertical alignment?

Comment: For an Android noob without prior XML layout experience this isn't intuitive. Why does "wrapping" affect centre alignment?

Answer (score 1):

Put the text in a box and set `contentAlignment` of the Box to center.

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){
    Text(
        text = "Select Bank account",
        color = Color.White,
        fontSize = 18.sp,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Black)
            .padding(16.dp)
            .align(Alignment.Center)
    )
}
```

Comment: In question is mentioned: "Looking for a solution without using another component wrapping the text. (Box, Column, etc)"